# Nuget console blocked by security settings, cannot run any commands

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2013, nuget

**Platform:** VS2013 update 5 on Windows 7, on a large centrally managed network with heavy restrictions on security policies at both network and local PC level. Asking the network powers-that-be to make changes just for me are absolutely not an option.

**The Problem:** Cannot run Nuget Package Manager Console. At all. It will not initialize. I am trying to run it in order to enable and use code-first migrations. When attempting to start the console I receive a lengthy error message in red text stating:

"Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by a policy defined at a more specific scope. Due to the override, your shell will retain its current effective execution policy of "Unrestricted". Type "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List" to view your execution policy settings. For more information, please see "Get-Help Set-ExecutionPolicy."

**What I've Done:** Opened PowerShell using my administrator account and ran "Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned" from another SO answer. Received error that the policy was set but was overridden by a more specific policy which would be retained. I then ran "Get-ExecutionPolicy -List" with the following result:

```
MachinePolicy    Unrestricted
UserPolicy       Undefined
Process          Undefined
CurrentUser      Undefined
LocalMachine     RemoteSigned
```

At this point I don't know what to do. I can move the VS solution file to an off-network machine that has unrestricted wifi access to download nuget packages, but I am specifically trying to enable code-first migrations for Entity Framework 6 (which I've never done before) to convert the project over from my DB-first model to code-first generated from DB. This is not something I can do off-network as the databases I have to access are enterprise databases on the restricted network. My reading shows that the EDMX DB-first model approach will be removed in EF7 so I want to get started the right way, which Microsoft is clearly implying will be code first migrations. If I can't run the package manager console then I can't run migrations, which then sounds like I won't be able to move to EF7, which will stall development. So I want to get started properly if at all possible.

Any advice/guidance on how to handle this situation much appreciated. Specifically I'm wondering if there is a way I can route around this problem and use the console properly. Thanks.

Comment: Encountered this same issue after installing update 5. Upgrading nuget (to 2.8.60723.765) solved my problem

Comment: @jbl Interesting... I'm currently on 2.8.60610.756, will try updating to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: @jbl That worked perfectly thanks for the tip. If you add that as an answer I'll accept it so you can get credit for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, I encountered a similar issue after installing update 5 of Visual Studio 2013.

Upgrading nuget (to 2.8.60723.765) solved my problem.

Comment: This was the solution. Thanks.